# adding item to listbox

Tags: vba, listbox, addition, lines

I can add Specific lines from textbox to listbox like this :

```
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(0))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(1))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(2))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(3))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(4))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(5))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(6))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(7))
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(8))
```

Is there an easier way? from line0 to line50? 
annotation : not all lines.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
For i = 0 To 50
  If i <> 10 And i <> 20 Then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Lines(i))
  End If
Next i
```

=> This would add all items except Line 10 and Line 20.

Comment: Exactly ... Thank you